# html разметку внутрь popover (bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap4

появилась необходимость выводить (не маленький не большой 50-100 строк) блок html кода (не модальным окном), а замечательно для этого подошел бы popover который у нас в проекте уже включен.

Контент генерируется циклом и собственно блоки будут разные вместе с кнопками вызывающими popover.

Буду очень признателен если кто то подскажет, верно ли класть html блок внутрь popover, и если да то как лучше всего это осуществить.

В html блоке так же присутствует svg (это я к тому, что побывал заменять все двойные кавычки на одинарные при этом слетает svg)
 Спасибо!

Comment: вы документацию то потрудились почитать? неужели там не написано, для чего использовать popover в отличие от того же tooltip, а также способы задания внутреннего контента?

Comment: Вопрос был срочный об этом забыл. Если ответ есть в документации вопрос закрыт. Благодарю